# How to retrieve values from database and row in gridview based on rows in table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I want to retrieve values in gridview based on the rows in database

I tried it's working but values are not there in controls

I have 2 rows in table

**Edit:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-BackColor="DarkCyan" HeaderText="Activities">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="dropActivities" Width="150px" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-BackColor="OliveDrab" HeaderText="Monday">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-BackColor="OliveDrab" HeaderText="Tuesday">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-BackColor="OliveDrab" HeaderText="Wednesday">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-BackColor="OliveDrab" HeaderText="Thursday">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-BackColor="OliveDrab" HeaderText="Friday">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-BackColor="OliveDrab" HeaderText="Saturday">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-BackColor="OliveDrab" HeaderText="Sunday">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostback)
    {
      bind();
    }
}

private void bind()
{
    int rowIndex = 0;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow drow = null;
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column0", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column4", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column5", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column6", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column7", typeof(string)));

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select activities,monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,sunday from activity_values where week = '" + weekNumNow + "' and emp_id = (select emp_id from emp_master where username = '" + username + "')", DbConnection);
        DbConnection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr1.Read())
        {
            drow = dt.NewRow();
            //Here I can get the values
            drow["Column0"] = dr1[0].ToString();
            drow["Column1"] = dr1[1].ToString();
            drow["Column2"] = dr1[2].ToString();
            drow["Column3"] = dr1[3].ToString();
            drow["Column4"] = dr1[4].ToString();
            drow["Column5"] = dr1[5].ToString();
            drow["Column6"] = dr1[6].ToString();
            drow["Column7"] = dr1[7].ToString();
            dt.Rows.Add(drow);
            dt.AcceptChanges();

            rowIndex++;
        }
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
        Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
        Gridview1.DataBind();
    }
```

In the gridview rows are added but showing empty values
[image]

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: How does your gridview definition looks like in .aspx?

Comment: 1st check that your query is returning you any results, if yes check the init of the grid, e.g AutogenerateColumns is set to true

I believe that the query doesnt return any results though check and come back.

Comment: I think `AutoGenerateColumns` should be set to `false`. And have you tried using `dt.Load(dr1)` instead of adding the columns yourself and filling them manually to `dt`?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `Eval` to show the data in gridview as follows

```
<asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-BackColor="DarkCyan" HeaderText="Activities">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="dropActivities" Width="150px" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-BackColor="OliveDrab" HeaderText="Monday">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("monday") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-BackColor="OliveDrab" HeaderText="Tuesday">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("tuesdady") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-BackColor="OliveDrab" HeaderText="Wednesday">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("wednesday") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-BackColor="OliveDrab" HeaderText="Thursday">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("thursday") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-BackColor="OliveDrab" HeaderText="Friday">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("friday") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-BackColor="OliveDrab" HeaderText="Saturday">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("saturday") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-BackColor="OliveDrab" HeaderText="Sunday">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("sunday") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and your `bind()` method could be made simpler like this

```
private void bind()
{
    int rowIndex = 0;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select activities,monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,sunday from activity_values where week = '" + weekNumNow + "' and emp_id = (select emp_id from emp_master where username = '" + username + "')", DbConnection);
    DbConnection.Open();
    OleDbDataReader dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dt.Load(dr1);
    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
    Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
    Gridview1.DataBind();
}
```

`dt.Load()` will create the required columns to the `dt` automatically.

**Edit** if you want to show an empty row for data entry use `<emptydatatemplate>` inside gridview like this

```
<asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
    .//
    .//keep same
    .//
    </Columns>
    <emptydatatemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="dropActivities" Width="150px" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
                </td>
                .//
                .//And so on
                .//
            </tr>
        </table>
    </emptydatatemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response..I hope this code should work but how to achieve this http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/08/02/save-dynamic-textbox-values-from-gridview-to-database.aspx if I don't have any values in table I want to show one row in gridview...